# Howto run XLIST command in python imap lib on google imap server?

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I want to run XLIST command from python lib, anyone know how? (there is nothing about this command in python docs). This question address [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185391/localized-gmail-imap-folders).

Answer (score 1):

This command is not implemented by imaplib.

I know this is a bit of a hack but I really needed to run XLIST for the exact same reason.

Looking at how list() was implemented in imaplib source, I inherited the imaplib's IMAP4_SSL class and added the xlist() command. So, in adv_imaplib.py add:

```
import imaplib

imaplib.Commands['XLIST'] =  ('AUTH', 'SELECTED')

class ADV_IMAP4_SSL(imaplib.IMAP4_SSL):

  def xlist(self, directory='""', pattern='*'):
    """(X)List mailbox names in directory matching pattern. Using Google's XLIST extension

    (typ, [data]) = <instance>.xlist(directory='""', pattern='*')

    'data' is list of XLIST responses.
    """
    name = 'XLIST'
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, directory, pattern)
    return self._untagged_response(typ, dat, name)
```

now just create ADV_IMAP4_SSL instead of IMAP4_SSL and call xlist(), works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is to use the 3rd party [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com) library.

It supports XLIST [out of the box](http://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#imapclient.IMAPClient.xlist_folders).