# Accessing Gmails SPAM Folder from PHP

Tags: php, gmail, imap, spam

How does one access the SPAM folder from a Gmail account using PHP? Here is my code for connecting to gmails imap server. When I replace INBOX with SPAM it results in an exception:

```
$mailbox = imap_open("{imap.googlemail.com:993/ssl}INBOX", "USERNAME@googlemail.com", "PASSWORD");
$mail = imap_search($mailbox, "ALL");
$mail_headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $mail[0]);
$subject = $mail_headers->subject;
$from = $mail_headers->fromaddress;
imap_close($mailbox);
```

Comment: How to do you connect to gmail? Show your code...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185391/localized-gmail-imap-folders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/open-mailbox-other-than-inbox-php-imap/) it looks like the folder name would be `[Google Mail]/Spam` or `[Gmail]/Spam`