# IMAP error unknown mailbox when i change language in my gmail

Tags: node.js, express, imap

I am trying to fetch a users emails and show it in my app. I am using imap for this. It works if the language setting in gmail is english but dosent work for any other languages. I am opening his inbox through the imap.openBox() function . The problem with this is i have to give which box i want to open as first argument of the openBox function. So if a user changes his language setting it fails because i am trying to open his inbox like imap.openBox('inbox'). Is there any other way to open his inbox using imap where the language dosent become an issue. I am using an express server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localized Gmail IMAP Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185391/localized-gmail-imap-folders)

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate. FWIW opening ["inbox" always works](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-87), other mailboxes are as in the other questions.